# I'm looking for an iphone alarm app with both programmable days and gradual alarm sound

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, alarm

- It has to have days of the week to repeat alarms, i forget to set them otherwise. the default clock app has it.
- Alarms should get gradually louder, i'm sick of scrambling to silence the phone as soon as it starts screaming at me. It's not a very nice start to every day.

Comment: I'm used to using Sleep As Android which has exactly what I want. I hope Apple can top that app.

Answer (score 2):

There are two apps that I've investigated:

- [Sleep Cycle](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/sleep-cycle-alarm-clock/id320606217?mt=8)
- [Rise](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/rise-alarm-clock/id577221529?mt=8)

Sleep Cycle has an alarm that gets louder, whilst also waking you during a "window" of the most opportune time, so you feel brighter and fresher.

Both have a setting for weekends and days of the week so you can set the alarm for whatever days you want.

I recommend both. At the moment I'm using Rise, but you have to pay for it.

Comment: I downloaded Sleep Cycle and will probably use it, however it doesn't have programmable days like the default apple alarm does.

Comment: I disagree - Sleep Cycle has programmable days, at least for binary alarm off / on days. To what greater detail do you want programmable days. Do you mean multiple alarms with different combinations of days? Or you could just not turn the alarm on for that day as you have to actively lay it on your pillow and sleep with it face down?